# UTF8 doesn't get parsed by php, server related ? not file related

Tags: php, wordpress, utf-8, host

this is so weird, this has never happened to me. I've worked with utf-8 alot and this is the first time happening,
**Since last week** all my sites that had utf8 characters in files are now showing `?` instead of the actual character!

the files are ok and I can see characters fine if I edit them,but after it gets processed by php it changes the utf-8 characters with `?`.

the utf8 characters that were stored in database are loading just fine , but the problem is with the strings that are in php files.

Notice I said **since last week**,  this means it happened all of a sudden and obviously something changed on server.
I contacted my hosting company but they have no clue what to look for and I don't know what to tell them to look for.

any clue what could have been changed on the server?

so to conclude:

- it's not a database problem
- it's not a file encoding problem (I hope not, I have 30+ sites with different cms on each one, **can not** afford to edit them all)
- it's not a content-type issue in html because it's getting parsed by php and turns utf8 characters to  `?`
- it could alse be a wordpress problem,but I'm sure this happend after some changes on server side

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0slkJ.jpg)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJTZ0.jpg)

Comment: can you try to isolate the problem and give a small piece of demonstration code of your "utf-8 parsing"? I assume it's because of the HTTP `Content-Type` header changed, but you mention it cannot be a problem with content type. so give us an example please.

Comment: ok for example it changes : قیمت to ????? (I looked in the html source code too,after it's loaded its question marks )besides I have like 30+ sites with different html codes some don't have content-type,but most of them have it and they have the same problem.

Comment: And please give some more information: what webserver and what php version is this? Apache 2 + mod_php 5.3.x?

Comment: Is it the actual ? character or the � character for invalid byte-sequence

Comment: I know what it changes the characters to. I was asking for example **code**

Comment: ok here are screenshots [screen1](http://atrinco.com/img/images/12ntitled.jpg)    [screen2](http://atrinco.com/img/images/22titled.jpg)

Comment: PHP Version : 5.2.17 , LiteSpeed V5.5

Comment: ok, i looked at the site woodpress.ir headers in firebug (this is the site that you say in your screenshot).

In the header response, `content-type` is `utf-8`, but when i right click on the page and see `"page info"`, it says "Standards Compliance Mode"....please put this in your page: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` and try again.

Comment: I already said that I don't think it's html/file related, I did it anyway, check again nothing has changed.

Comment: Do you use output buffering and are you doing anything string related there? What *are* you doing to the strings?

Comment: I do absolutely nothing, it was all ok  ,this happend suddenly 1 week ago.

Comment: Double check it's not an encoding issue during file transfer (i.e. when you upload your templates). Try uploading a very simple doc with no php in it. If these strings are also stored into the DB - have a look at the DB/table/column encoding.

Comment: no it's not from the database,these strings aren't stored in db,they are saved in file,db strings are loading just fine. it could also be wordpress problem,but something must have changed on server

Answer (score 1):

- it's not a database problem - Check
- it's not a file encoding problem - THIS actually could be it
- it's not a content-type - Check (but make sure you write UTF-8 in meta tag lowercase !)
- Wordpress problem - Maybe with combination of file encoding

I can imagine situation, when you deleted/disabled mb_string module for PHP and then edited your template using wordpress. Then your characted got shattered.

Comment: it might actually be the mb_string's fault . if they have changed or deleted/disabled it, it might cause it. I realized something after a couple of tests, the files that have been saved with utf-8 with BOM are showing the question marks,if I save them again with utf-8 it will solve the problem. but I have too many files on many sites,that can't be done. does anyone have any idea how to solve this by server change ? I want to tell my hosting to do it.

Comment: If you're not programmer, ask you hosting provider to do it. Otherwise write yourself a simple script that will do the job.

Comment: I want to keep the option of changing files encoding to the last, because most editors save with utf-8 with bom as default and this will keep happening,I'll try to talk to my host,btw can "enable-zend-multibyte" cause this ?

Comment: ok my host is avoiding the problem because they don't know how to fix it,they sat the only thing they have done is rebuilt the PHP. does anybody have any idea ?